# How to create a dynamic security group based on employeeId field

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, regex-group

I am trying to create a dynamic security group in Azure Active directory based on **employeeId** field.
Bakcground info: Each employee in my organization has an employeeId in active directory which is either five characters long or four characters long depending on the type of employee. for example,

- full-Time employees - employeeId is always 5 numbers long, e.g 12345
- Contract employees - employeeId is always 4 numbers long, e.g 4321

The employeeId is always a number.
I want to create a **dynamic security group** in azure active directory for both using the following rules:

- All Full-time employees — employeeId -match #####
- All contract employees — employeeId -match ####

I understand from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-dynamic-membership#using-the--match-operator) that the **-match** operator supports regular expressions. Problem is I am completely new to regular expressions and don't know how to achieve my scenario. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Rule syntax to limit the length of the number string to 4-5:

```
(user.employeeId -match "^[0-9]{4,5}$")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer @Allen Wu ! You just saved my day. Setting up these groups will make our company environment more secure and controlled. Thanks again!